# Creating date strings and setting dates

Tags: java, object-oriented, datetime

I've created a Java class, `Date`, in which I basically create date strings and set dates.  Is there anything I can do besides adding comments to improve/shorten my code?

I've tested all of my methods to see if they work correctly, and they all work as planned. I haven't done tests that force the `IllegalArgumentsException` to be thrown yet though.

I've tried changing the instantiated `boolean` variable `shortDisplay` have a default value of true, which has made my program work correctly as far as I know.

I'm assuming when you declare a `boolean` instance variable, you need to also declare what its default value should be, otherwise issues arise. If anyone could comment on why that is, that would be great.

**Date.java**

```
public class Date {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private boolean shortDisplay = true;

    public Date() {
        setDate(2000, 01, 01);
    }

    public Date(int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        setDate(yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public Date(int yy, int mm) {
        setDate(yy, mm);
    }

    public Date(int yy) {
        setDate(yy);
    }

    public Date(Date otherDate) {
        setDate(otherDate);
    }

    public Date(String dateStr) {
        setDate(dateStr);
    }

    public void setDate(int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        setYear(yy);
        setMonth(mm);
        setDay(dd);
    }

    public void setDate(int yy, int mm) {
        setYear(yy);
        setMonth(mm);
        setDay(1);
    }

    public void setDate(int yy) {
        setYear(yy);
        setMonth(1);
        setDay(1);
    }

    public void setDate(Date otherDate) {
        int yy = getYear();
        int mm = getMonth();
        int dd = getDay();
        setYear(yy);
        setMonth(mm);
        setDay(dd);
    }

    public void setDate(String dateStr) {
        int length = dateStr.length();
        int indexCount = 0;
        if (length >= 0) { // basically checking to see if the date even exists
            if (dateStr.indexOf('/') >= 0) {
                int index = dateStr.indexOf('/');
                indexCount++;
                String dd = dateStr.substring(index+1, dateStr.length());
                if (dd.substring(1, dd.length()).lastIndexOf('/') >= 0 ) {
                    int index2 =  dd.lastIndexOf('/');
                    indexCount++;
                    String yy = dd.substring(index2+1, dd.length());
                    if (yy.lastIndexOf('/') >= 0) {
                        indexCount++;
                    }
                    String mm = dateStr.substring(0, index);
                    dd = dd.substring(0, index2);
                    yy = yy.substring(0, yy.length());
                    System.out.println(mm + "\n" + dd + "\n" + yy );
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(yy);
                    int d = Integer.parseInt(dd);
                    int m = Integer.parseInt(mm);
                    setYear(y);
                    setMonth(m);
                    setDay(d);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void setYear(int yy) {
        if (yy >= 1900) {
            year = yy;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("lol");
        }
    }

    public void setMonth(int mm) {
        if (mm >= 1 && mm <= 12) {
            month = mm;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not cool");
        }
    }

    public void setDay(int dd) {
        if (dd >= 1 && dd <= 31) {
            day = dd;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("stupid");
        }
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setShortDisplay() {
        shortDisplay = true;
    }

    public void setLongDisplay() {
        shortDisplay = false;
    }

    public boolean isShortDisplay() {
        if (shortDisplay) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void incrementDay() {
        day++;
        if (day > 31) {
            day = 1;
            incrementMonth();
        }
    }

    public void incrementMonth() {
        month++;
        if (month > 12) {
            month = 1;
            incrementYear();
        }
    }

    public void incrementYear() {
        year++;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        Date that = (Date) other;
        if (this.day == that.day && this.month == that.month && this.year == that.year) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean before(Date otherDate) {
        Date that = otherDate; 
        if (this.year < that.year) return true;
        if (this.month < that.month) return true;
        if (this.day < that.day) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        boolean check = isShortDisplay();
        if (check) {
            if (month < 10 && day < 10) {
                return "0" + month + "/" + "0" + day + "/" + year;
            }
            if (month < 10 && day > 10) {
                return "0" + month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            }
            if (month > 10 || day < 10) {
                return month + "/" + "0" + day + "/" + year;
            } else {
                return  month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            }
        } else {
            return monthString(month) + " " + day + ", " + year;
        }
    }

    public static String monthString(int month) {
        if (month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
            String[] stringMonth = {"", "January", "February", "March", "April", "June", "July",
                "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
        return stringMonth[month];
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

**DateTest.java**

```
public class DateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Date d = new Date(2013, 4, 9);
        System.out.println(d);
        d.setLongDisplay();
        System.out.println(d);

        Date d1 = new Date();
        if (!d1.toString().equals("01/01/2000")) {
            System.out.println("Error 1");
        }

        d1.setDate("4/8/2013");
        if (!d1.toString().equals("04/08/2013")) {
            System.out.println("Error 2");
        }

        d1.setDay(28);
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            d1.incrementDay();
        }

        System.out.println(d1);

        if (!d1.toString().equals("05/02/2013")) {
            System.out.println("Error 3");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Your class does not handle months with less than 31 days, in-real-life-speaking your unit test for adding five days to 28th April is already wrong**
- `stringMonth` can be left as a `private static final` array, so that you are not re-creating it every time `monthString()` is called
- `equals()` implementation does not check for null/class type, and by right you should have a corresponding `hashCode()` implementation too
- `before()` can probably be better implemented as `compareTo()` if you can consider letting your class implement `Comparable`
- There are better ways of formatting the `String` representation in `toString()` and parsing a `String` date in `setDate(String dateStr)`
- Some Javadocs will be helpful too, especially to indicate the format that you are using in `toString()` (`"MM/DD/YY"`)
- Consider a proper testing framework such as JUnit or TestNG?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of putting print statements in the `main` method, it would be better to write proper unit tests. That way you don't have to read the output and understand if it's correct or not, the assertions will take care of that for you, so you can focus on just what fails after you changed something. For example using JUnit4:

```
public class DateTest {
    @Test
    public void testShortAndLongDisplay() {
        Date d = new Date(2013, 4, 9);
        Assert.assertEquals("04/09/2013", d.toString());
        d.setLongDisplay();
        Assert.assertEquals("April 9, 2013", d.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetDate() {
        Date d1 = new Date();
        Assert.assertEquals("01/01/2000", d1.toString());

        d1.setDate("4/8/2013");
        Assert.assertEquals("04/08/2013", d1.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIncrementDay() {
        Date d1 = new Date(2013, 4, 28);
        Assert.assertEquals("04/28/2013", d1.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            d1.incrementDay();
        }
        Assert.assertEquals("05/02/2013", d1.toString());
    }
}
```

---

There is a bug in the `before` method, as it fails this unit test (the second assert):

```
@Test
public void testBefore() {
    Date d1 = new Date(2013, 4, 28);
    Date d2 = new Date(2013, 5, 27);
    Assert.assertTrue(d1.before(d2));
    Assert.assertFalse(d2.before(d1));
}
```

---

Some problems in the `setDate` method:

- `indexCount` is incremented but never used
- You should not print things in code with `System.out.println`. You might want to use a `Logger` instead.

---

If you don't plan to create sub-classes of this one, then it's better to access `shortDisplay` directly within the class instead of the `isShortDisplay` accessor. But if you do plan sub-classes then never mind.

---

This can be simplified:

> ```
> public boolean isShortDisplay() {
>     if (shortDisplay) {
>         return true;
>     } else {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

Since `shortDisplay` is a boolean variable, you can simply return it:

```
public boolean isShortDisplay() {
    return shortDisplay;
}
```

---

As others pointed out, the `equals` method doesn't check for null and class type. Also, the if-else there can be simplified:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        Date that = (Date) obj;
        return this.day == that.day
                && this.month == that.month
                && this.year == that.year;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's also nice to explicitly add the `@Override` annotation when you're overriding a superclass method, just in case somebody reads the code (or a diff) outside a nice IDE.

And when you implement an `equals` method, you should also implement a `hashCode` method to ensure consistency, how about:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", day, month, year).hashCode();
}
```

---

> ```
> setDate(2000, 01, 01);
> ```

IntelliJ gives me a warning about this, because `01` is an octal integer... Very cosmetic, but maybe you can just drop those zeros anyway....

Comment: "because `01` is an octal integer" Good catch, this means `08` wouldn't work. ;)

Comment: I had the idea of returning something like what your `hashCode()` does, but I didn't know how to properly make that work. I haven't learned about using something like `String.format`, so I tried using `printf`. Also the `print` statements were there because I was having issues with grabbing the right numbers from a given string date, and so I used them to see what was being created. Thanks for all the tips.

Comment: @h.j.k. with the `equals()` method, shouldn't I also add another `else` statement to see if the variable is also of type `String` since one of my constructors takes in a variable of type `String`? If so, is it appropriate in my `Date` class to use on of the constructors inside another method, i.e. `Date that = new Date(other)` when `other` is a string?

Comment: @cbenn95 If you consult the Javadoc for `equals()` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), one of this method's property should be that it is symmetric, `x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x)`. Since we can't possibly make a `String` object be equal to your `Date` object, you should not check for equality against `String` objects.

Comment: Furthermore, even if a `String test = "20140422"` does equal to a `Date temp = new Date(2014,4,22)` in non-programming terms, the way the hash code is calculated will be different between the two.


It is not a convention to compare equality across different classes. It may make some sense between parent and child classes or classes meant to be used internally/strictly according to some explicit assumptions, but that's about all I can think of.

Comment: @h.j.k. is there any way that I can take in the object and make a variable of type `Date` from the object when the object's type is `String`? The only reason I'm asking about this is because I can't seem to implement any of the ways I know of to get the method to do just that. In the sample execution of DateTest.java my teacher gave me, no errors occur. In mine, when it comes to comparing a string to a string created from the date, I always get a returned value of false. I know why, and it's because my program is using the `String.equals()` method and not `Date.equals()`.

Comment: @cbenn95 if that's the case, I'll prefer having a new static method e.g. `isEquivalentToString()` that internally creates a `Date` object from the `String` for the comparison you require. With all these being said, at the end of the day code is just code written for your assignment and requirements, so if it's required to support `String` comparison in the `equals()` method then that should be explicitly mentioned at least. I'll certainly be puzzled if I come across such an implementation without explanation though.

Comment: @h.j.k. okay. Thanks for all the advice, it's certainly helped and I appreciate you taking time to help me out!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to write your own Date class. In Java you can use [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), or [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) with [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). If you need your own Date class, you can write for instance a wrapper class or write an Util class.

Java Date API is ugly. In java 8 there is a new more usable date API. In earlier versions I recommend [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 3rd party library.

### Review of Your code:

1. **Unit tests**:
   There are tools such as [JUnit](http://junit.org/) or [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) to test your code. This way you can write more reusable, simpler, easy-to-use, automated tests. The real unit tests help your work, for instance you can describe the the expected behaviour in a more proper way.
2. **Your Date class**:

   - **Constructors**
     There are a lot of constructors with different number of parameters. You can "embed" them with the `this(...)` method. For example:

     ```
     public Date() {
     //  setDate(2000, 01, 01);
       this(2000, 1, 1);
     }
     ```
   - **Setters**

     - The `setDate(...)` methods can invoke each similar as I wrote in the constructor section.
     - The `setDate(Date otherDate)` method is not working now. It's setting the owned values now. Instead of you can use:

       ```
       public void setDate(final Date otherDate) {
           year = otherDate.year;
           month = otherDate.month;
           day = otherDate.day;
       }
       ```
     - The `setDay(...)`, `setYear(...)`, `setMonth(...)` methods are invoked in the class for example in the constructors or in other setters. *Robert Cecil Martin: Clean Code* says: One Level of Abstraction per Function in Chapter 3: functions. So you can separate the validating from the setters for example this way:

       ```
       private static final int MINIMUM_YEAR = 1900;

       public void setYear(final int year) {
           this.year = checkYear(year);
       }

       public int checkYear(final int year) {
           if (year >= MINIMUM_YEAR) {
               return year;
           }

           throw new IllegalArgumentException("The year must be greater than " + MINIMUM_YEAR);
       }
       ```

       Here 1900 was a "magic number", you should name it for increase readability.
       You should name your variables what they exactly. `yy` is ok in a date format, but as a variable it's exactly a year. Don't mind if it's hiding a field, in Java you can access your fields through `this.`. For example `this.year`.
     - The `setDate(String dateStr)` method is so unreadable and splitting string with indexOf is so hard. You can use [String.split(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for example to get the values.

       - The `dateAsString` name is more readable than `dateStr`.
       - The `indexCount` variable is not used so you can remove it.
       - As Joshua Bloch's Effective Java says: Whenever possible use final variables. This minimize the scope of local variables.
     - Your `setDate(...)` methods of your **Date** class has tricky name, because in proper way one setter sets one field. So the year, month, day field trio represents the date here. It's not a main problem, but decreasing the code's readability.
   - `monthString(int month)`
     You should use a private `static array` or an `enum class`, to don't redefine the mounts on every invocation.